# Read binary file of logging data and output to new file with int (python)

Tags: python, binary, hex, binaryfiles, hex-file

I've been working on an embedded software project that writes sensor data to SD card using FATFS module. The datatype of the data is uint32_t (4 bytes) and the output is binary file.

I'm trying to write a python script to read the binary file (and parse the data to int and write to a new file). My current code,

```
def read():
with open("INPUT1.TXT", "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    print(data)
```

and that gives me a chunk of value in hex,

```
    b'    \x01   \x02   \x03   \x04   \x05   \x06   \x07   \x08   \t   \n   \x0b   \
x0c   \r   \x0e   \x0f   \x10   \x11   \x12   \x13   \x14   \x15   \x16   \x17
 \x18   \x19   \x1a   \x1b   \x1c   \x1d   \x1e   \x1f       \x01   \x02   \x03
  \x04   \x05   \x06   \x07   \x08   \t   \n   \x0b   \x0c   \r   \x0e   \x0f
\x10   \x11   \x12   \x13   \x14   \x15   \x16   \x17   \x18   \x19   \x1a   \x1
b   \x1c   \x1d   \x1e   \x1f      '
```

When printing each 4 bytes, some numbers are even missing,

```
f = open("INPUT2.TXT", "rb")
try:
    bytes_read = f.read(4)
    while bytes_read:
        print(bytes_read)
        bytes_read = f.read(4)
finally:
    f.close()
```

give result of

```
b'    '       #supposed to be \x00
b'\x01   '
b'\x02   '
b'\x03   '
b'\x04   '
b'\x05   '
b'\x06   '
b'\x07   '
b'\x08   '
b'\t   '      #supposed to be \x09
b'\n   '      #supposed to be \x0a
b'\x0b   '
b'\x0c   '
b'\r   '      #supposed to be \x0d
b'\x0e   '
b'\x0f   '
b'\x10   '
b'\x11   '
b'\x12   '
b'\x13   '
b'\x14   '
b'\x15   '
b'\x16   '
b'\x17   '
b'\x18   '
b'\x19   '
b'\x1a   '
b'\x1b   '
b'\x1c   '
b'\x1d   '
b'\x1e   '
b'\x1f   '
```

But when I read the binary file in a hex editor, all the binary appears to be correct?!

If I want to read 4 bytes at a time, and write to a new file (in type int), how could I achieve it?

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? There are some slight differences.

Comment: check [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) out for why you think you're "missing" data, because you aren't missing any from what I can tell

Comment: @youngmit I'm using python 3.

Comment: @jacoblaw I still don't get it... Is there any way in python to print all the data, but in type of int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nums = []
with open("INPUT2.TXT", "rb") as file:
    while byte:
        byte = file.read(4)
        nums.append(int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder="little"))
```

This should do it for python 3.

It looks like your bytes are flipped from your example, so I changed byte order to little. if they aren't flipped, then change it back to big.

Another weird thing: it looks like 0x00 is getting turned into b" ", instead of b"\x00". if that's the case, then do this instead:

```
nums = []
with open("INPUT2.TXT", "rb") as file:
    while byte:
        byte = file.read(4)
        nums.append(int.from_bytes(byte.replace(b" ", b"\x00"), byteorder="little"))
```

Here's an example with what you provided.

```
>>> test = [b'    ',
b'\x01   ',
b'\x02   ',
b'\x03   ',
b'\x04   ',
b'\x05   ',
b'\x06   ',
b'\x07   ',
b'\x08   ',
b'\t   ',
b'\n   ',
b'\x0b   ',
b'\x0c   ',
b'\r   ',
b'\x0e   ',
b'\x0f   ',
b'\x10   ',
b'\x11   ',
b'\x12   ',
b'\x13   ',
b'\x14   ',
b'\x15   ',
b'\x16   ',
b'\x17   ',
b'\x18   ',
b'\x19   ',
b'\x1a   ',
b'\x1b   ',
b'\x1c   ',
b'\x1d   ',
b'\x1e   ',
b'\x1f   ']

>>> for t in test:
>>>     print(int.from_bytes(t.replace(b" ", b"\x00"),  byteorder="little"))
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I got a very similar result with Gribouillis answer. The nums give me a really big number (invalid) [538976288, 18882592, 35659808, 52437024, 69214240, 85991456, 102768672, 119545888, 136323104, 153100320, 169877536,...]. Do you know why?

Comment: @shjnlee Hey i just updated it, should work with the edit

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do it with

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 4)
    d = struct.unpack('I', data[i:i+4])
    print(d)
```

Comment: I tried your code, and the data after unpack are not valid (i.e. 538976288, 538976258,...).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just uint32_t numbers packed into a binary file, I think you can use the `read()` function on the file

```
num_list = []
with open("INPUT1.TXT", "rb") as binary_file:
    byte_data = 0x1 # Initial placeholder for the loop
    while byte_data:  
        byte_data = binary_file.read(4) # 4 being the number of bytes to read at a time
        num_list.append(int(byte_data))
#  Do something with num_list
```

Comment: There may be something not right with the conversion int(byte_data). I put a try block cause it complains some exception and print the num_list, but it's empty.